# Change MySQL root password with bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm attempting to create a bash script to change the MySQL root password, below is the current snippet of code I am working with:

```
#!/bin/sh
clear
echo "Enter the current password for the root mysql account."

read oldrootpass

echo "Enter a new password for the root mysql account."

read newrootpass
mysql -u root -p$oldrootpass -Bse 'UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD("$newrootpass") WHERE User="root"'
```

The syntax above for changing the root password may not be correct, but the part I am stuck on is generating a one line command to work with mysql, if the command goes over 2 lines then the MySQL prompt is entered and the MySQL commands in the bash script are executed once the MySQL prompt has been closed with the 'exit' command.

My intention is to gather the relevant password information via the bash script, run a single command to change the root password and then return back to the bash script, or bash prompt is the script has ended.

Comment: First: Variables within single quotes don't get expanded. This will set your root password to the string "$newrootpass".

Comment: Thank you for adding this, I realised my mistake after getting the mysql syntax to execute and alternated the single and double quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're asking how to run more than one statement with a single `mysql` command, you can either simply separate them by semicolons:

```
$ mysql -e 'select 1; select 2'
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
+---+
| 2 |
+---+
| 2 |
+---+
```

or you can create a file containing the SQL statements and run that:

```
$ mysql < change_password.sql
```

Comment: Thank you, for now I'm still using purely the bash script, using your help I've managed to generate the following bash command to change the password: - mysql -u root -p$oldrootpass -e "show databases; use mysql; UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD('$newrootpass') WHERE User='root'; flush privileges;"

Answer (score 10):

Use mysqladmin instead of running a query in mysql.

`mysqladmin -u root -p'$oldrootpass' password '$newrootpass'`

should work but you might need to mess with the quotes a little.